# Jadira dependency causes AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

Adding a Jadira dependency with Maven causes AbstractMethodError when trying to launch SpringApplication. There is nothing helpful in the stack trace; it is not referencing any of my own classes. What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Here is the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
    <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.CR1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is part of the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    ...
    at sec.project.CyberSecurityBaseProjectApplication.main(CyberSecurityBaseProjectApplication.java:17) [classes/:na] // this is simply the line that launches the Spring app
    ...
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    ...
```

FWIW, I was trying to do [this](http://blog.netgloo.com/2015/04/06/spring-boot-using-joda-time-on-jpa-entity-with-hibernate/).

Comment: An AbstractMethodError would tell you WHAT method of WHAT class is abstract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article you are referring to says that

> The code works with Spring Boot 1.2.2 and Hibernate 4.5

From your log it looks like you are using Spring Boot 1.4.2 which will fetch Hibernate 5 jars. There are some issues with Hibernate 5 and the old version of `jadira` (you are using 3.1.0.CR1). This issue has been fixed since 5.0.0.GA release of jadira usertype. Can you please try with new version available at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jadira.usertype/usertype.core

Comment: Did you try with 5.0.0.GA version? What error are you getting?

Comment: Oh, looks like 5.0.0.GA works (latest version doesn't). Thanks!

Comment: Yeah if you check latest version 6.0.1.GA, it supports Hibernate 5.2. Version 5.0.0.GA supports Hibernate 5.0 which is the version as per your log. Please accept the answer so it will be helpful for others.